# Not adding a column when reading a CSV file

Tags: r

I have this toy dataset, in a `CSV` file:

```
NAME, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3
due,2,2,2
tre,3,3,3
qua,3,4,3
cin,4,6,7
ddd,2,5,7
qse,7,6,5
```

I read it with the following command:
 data <- read.csv("path\to\file", head=TRUE, sep=",")

Then if I try to print `data` I get this:

```
  NAME VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
1  due    2    2    2
2  tre    3    3    3
3  qua    3    4    3
4  cin    4    6    7
5  ddd    2    5    7
6  qse    7    6    5
```

I don't want the first column, I would like to have something in the same format of the `mtcars` dataset, where in the first columns I have the labels.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can I ask why you think this will help you with what you're eventually trying to achieve? Having the `NAME` values stored in the rownames of the dataframe will just make it harder to access those values as you're working with the dataset.

Comment: I'm trying to do some clustering, and if I use the dataset with numbers in the first column, the labels of the dendrogram are the IDs ad not the names. Please, if you think that it is stupid tell me, I have been using R just in the last two hours.

Comment: For your case, it is nice to have `row.names`. Marius was concerned about this usage not knowing what your purpose was, as it's quite unconventional (or difficult) if, for example, you want to aggregate or reshape etc. With `row.names` set, you can get the names in the plot directly. So, this is desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row.names=1` within `read.csv`:

```
read.csv(header=TRUE, row.names=1, text="NAME, VAL1, VAL2, VAL3
    due,2,2,2
    tre,3,3,3
    qua,3,4,3
    cin,4,6,7
    ddd,2,5,7
    qse,7,6,5")

#     VAL1 VAL2 VAL3
# due    2    2    2
# tre    3    3    3
# qua    3    4    3
# cin    4    6    7
# ddd    2    5    7
# qse    7    6    5
```